# Show that two $ (a\times b) \times (c \times d) = <a \times c, d>b - <b\times c,d>a $ expressions are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$$ (a\times b) \times (c \times d) = <a \times c, d>b - <b\times c,d>a $$

$a,b,c,d$ .... unknown vectors

Show that the expression is equal.

I used the formula to get on the left side: $c((a \times b) d)-d((a\times b)c)$

I don't know how to continue.

EDIT:
$<a,b>$ ... means scalar product of a and b

Comment: It's clear that the LHS is in general a linear combination $\alpha a+\beta b$  of $a$ and $b$ (since it is perpendicular to $a\times b$). To find the coefficents just take cross products with $a$ and with $b$, it falls out.

Comment: @ancientmathematician But how does the associativity of the vectors work, I can't just remove the paranthesis

Comment: RHS notation is confusing.  What do > and < mean here?

Comment: it means scalar product

Comment: @herbsteinberg: these give the inner (dot) product.

Comment: You surely know the vector triple product formula? That lets you work out $a\times $LHS at once since $a\cdot (a\times b)=0$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I know the triple product formula, but isn't it so that

$$[a,b,c]d \neq a[b,c,d]$$

Comment: I think $(a\times c).d$ is easier on the eye than $<a \times c, d>$. But you also have $(a\times b)d$ in there, which is surely a typo.

Comment: Bili Debili: I do not understand your last comment. If you follow my recipe you will get the result.

Comment: Why not use langle and rangle instead of lt and gt signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Triple Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) reduces the RHS as follows
$$(d\cdot (a\times c))b -(d\cdot(b\times c))a = (a\cdot (c\times d))b - (b\cdot (c\times d))a$$
Next, we can let $v = c\times d$, and we now must show that
$$(a\times b) \times v = (a\cdot v)b - (b\cdot v)a$$
This should look easier to prove. For one, $(a\times b)$ is perpendicular to the plane formed by $a$ and $b$, and so $(a\times b)\times v$ will again lie on that plane. This means we can write $(a\times b) \times v$ as
$\alpha a + \beta b$.

To find $\alpha$ and $\beta$, first dot each side by $v$. The LHS is $0$ as $x\times v$ is perpendicular to $v$. Thus we know
$$0=\alpha a\cdot v + \beta b \cdot v$$
And so our formula holds up to scaling. Now just try it out for some combination of vectors and you can find the constant!

Answer (score 1):

$$V=(a \times b)\times (c \times d)=e \times (c \times d)= (e.d)c-(e.c)d=[a,b,d]c-[a,b,c]d$$
$p\times(q\times r)=(p.r)q-(p.q)r$ and $p.(q\times r)=[p,q,r]$